# How to output values from stored procedure controller to PostMan

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, asp.net-core, sql-server-2012

I have written a controller class that runs a stored procedure in SQL Server. I am able to run the controller just fine, and there are no connection issues to the database I need to access. However, when I use POSTMAN to GET the output from the API, I get an error "204 No Content", and no data is displayed (obviously).

I am using C# and ASP.NET Core 2.0 for this controller. I have already tested the stored procedure in SQL Server, and it works fine. The stored procedure is supposed to accept an input value and display a JSON string that is already formatted by the stored procedure itself.

My controller class:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ClassName([FromRoute] string input)
{
        string sqlcon = _iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("Database").Value;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(sqlcon))
        {
            string sql = "StoredProcedure";

            using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
            {
                SqlParameter outResult = new SqlParameter("@Output", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Input", input);
                com.Parameters.Add(outResult);

                var returnedName = outResult.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(returnedName);

                con.Open();

                com.ExecuteReader();
                con.Close();

                return Ok(returnedName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Postman is supposed to return a JSON output string based upon the input parameter (provided by me, in Postman). However, nothing is being returned in Postman. Does anybody know what potentially could be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure if your code has a typo when you posted it, but you have an `async` controller method but you're not using any async operations in it (you are using the synchronous version of `Open` as well as `ExecuteReader`), and there are no `await` keywords. If this is your actual code, maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Thanks @RyanWilson I just had to move my return values after the ExecuteReader command. Much appreciated